# Excel copy columns based on a condition

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a spreadsheet which I need to extract some data and copy it to a new sheet.

Below is an image of the spreadsheet. What I want is a copy of all the yellow highlighted columns in a new sheet when column M & Column N contain numbers (in this case there are only 2 that will be on the second sheet- row 7 & row 26). This sheet is quite big so this is just a sample.

[image]

```
Here is the code I have tried to use:

    Sub CopyYesAdrian()
Dim a As Variant, o As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets("Sheet1")
  a = .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
  n = Application.CountIf(.Columns(9), "Yes")
  ReDim o(1 To n + 1, 1 To 11)

End With
j = j + 1: o(j, 1) = "CORP ID": o(j, 2) = "Application ID"
o(j, 3) = "Orig - Country": o(j, 4) = "Network DDI": o(j, 5) = "PTT ACCESS": 
  o(j, 6) = "TERM - COUNTRY": o(j, 7) = "TERM SW/TRUNK"
: o(j, 8) = "TERM DIGITS": o(j, 9) = "PSTN ROUTE": o(j, 10) = "PLAN": o(j,  
11) = "DNIS"
For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
If IsError(a(i, 6)) Then

 ElseIf a(i, 8) = "Yes" And a(i, 6) Like "[0-9][0-9][0-9][/][0-9]*" Then
    j = j + 1: o(j, 1) = a(i, 1): o(j, 2) = a(i, 3)
    o(j, 3) = a(i, 4): o(j, 4) = a(i, 6): o(j, 5) = a(i, 8):  o(j, 6) = a(i,   
9):  o(j, 7) = a(i, 10):  o(j, 8) = a(i, 11)
:   o(j, 9) = a(i, 12):   o(j, 10) = a(i, 12):   o(j, 11) = a(i, 12)
  End If
Next i
With Sheets("Sheet2")
  .UsedRange.Clear
  .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(o, 1), UBound(o, 2)) = o
  .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
  .Activate
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: First, what have you tried so far? You suggest VBA, but are you comfortable using VBA? Please show the code that you have attempted, and show where it fails to do what you want/expect. Then, to clarify: if column M is a number, will column N also always be a number? Or vice versa?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get the code in one block for some odd reason. No they may not always be a number. sometimes there are strings in them but I only want to extract when there is numbers in both of them.

Comment: @grade The point failure is  `o(j, 1) = a(i, 1)`  its in the elseif statement. Some of the fields are not in the image an important 1 that is missing is column F which contains a concatenated value of column M & N (when there is a number in both)

Comment: I recommend you reformat your code so that each action taken is on its own line, rather than combining so many statements; I can't really parse what you're trying to do with that code block. Also - what happens at the "point of failure". Is there an error? What error? If not, what values appear that you wouldn't expect? Have you run through the code line by line to ensure that the variables are what you expect them to be?

Comment: @Grade the error I get is subscript out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your multi-statement lines with this:

```
j = j + 1
o(j, 1) = "CORP ID"
o(j, 2) = "Application ID"
o(j, 3) = "Orig - Country"
o(j, 4) = "Network DDI"
o(j, 5) = "PTT ACCESS"
o(j, 6) = "TERM - COUNTRY"
o(j, 7) = "TERM SW/TRUNK"
o(j, 8) = "TERM DIGITS"
o(j, 9) = "PSTN ROUTE"
o(j, 10) = "PLAN"
o(j, 11) = "DNIS"
For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
If IsError(a(i, 6)) Then

 ElseIf a(i, 8) = "Yes" And a(i, 6) Like "[0-9][0-9][0-9][/][0-9]*" Then
    j = j + 1
    o(j, 1) = a(i, 1)
    o(j, 2) = a(i, 3)
    o(j, 3) = a(i, 4)
    o(j, 4) = a(i, 6)
    o(j, 5) = a(i, 8)
    o(j, 6) = a(i, 9)
    o(j, 7) = a(i, 10)
    o(j, 8) = a(i, 11)
    o(j, 9) = a(i, 12)
    o(j, 10) = a(i, 12)
    o(j, 11) = a(i, 12)
End If
```

Please try this and let me know if it works.

Comment: I will let you know my result when I can test. Do you think it is possible to do what I am looking for, without using vba?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished without VBA (to an extent).

- Type the following formula into Sheet 2, cell A2:
  `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!$M2),ISNUMBER(Sheet1!$N2)),Sheet1!I2,"")`
- Copy/Paste this formula into cells B2:H2.
- Delete column C (it refers to column K in Sheet1, you don't want that).
- Select the entire row of formulas and copy down as many rows as are in Sheet 1.

This will get you as far as you've asked in the question, but I'm assuming you'll want to sort out the blank rows from there. In that case, you may want to make Sheet2 into a table so that you can filter out the blank rows.